# Search with removable inputs/label (Ionic 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a recipe app where I have a search and the user can search by the ingredient. I want the functionality to be when they touch the spacebar to type the next input for it to appear as a label below with a X next to it, therefore deselecting the relevant input.

My search currently looks like 
[image: Current]

But the aim is for it to look like with the label underneath.
[image: idea]

As this is for an Ionic 2 app, has anyone seen this done before or a tutorial? Or wants to give me some help, that would be great.

**NEW: Just noticed that the Stack overflow "Tags" section at the bottom of the page is the exact way I would like this implemented**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find something similar in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aRtJQ1?p=preview). There's a lot of room for improvements (and some more validations) but the demo is pretty much what you're looking for.

The code is very straightforward, the most relevant parts are:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  ...
  ...
})
export class HomePage {

  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public tags: Array<string>;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      tags: ['']
    });

    // Add an async validation for the username
    this.myForm.get('tags')
        .valueChanges
        .subscribe((value: string) => {
          if(value.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
            let newTag = value.split(' ')[0];
            console.log(newTag);
            if(newTag) {
              this.tags.push(newTag);
              this.myForm.get('tags').setValue('');
            }
          }
        });
  }

  public deleteTag(tagName: string) {
    // Find the index of the tag
    let index = this.tags.indexOf(tagName);

    // Delete the tag in that index
    this.tags.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>HomePage</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>      
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="tags" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </form>

  <div class="tag-container">
    <span class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
      {{ tag }}
      <ion-icon name="close" (click)="deleteTag(tag)"></ion-icon>
    </span>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And last but not least, the css!

```
.tag-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem from the point of view of the data model. When you isolate what you want down to its core, you want something such that for each input event on your search field,

1. you convert the search term into an array of words
2. you strip off the last word from that array and make that your array of labels
3. you take the last word of your array and make that the value of your input

So, let's say your component is like

```
@Component({
  .....
  template: `
    <input [formControl]="searchControl" (input)="onSearchInput(input.value)" />
    <label *ngFor="let label of labels">{{ label }} </label>
  `
})
export class SearchComponent {
  searchControl = new FormControl('');
  labels: string[] = [];

  onSearchInput(searchValue) {
    let newSearchValues: string[] = searchValue.split(' ');
    // if the current search term has a space,
    // create the new label and update the input field
    if (newSearchValues.length > 1) {
      this.labels.push(newSearchValues[0]);
      this.searchControl.setValue(newSearchValues[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

So, you bind your search input to a FormControl from the @angular/forms package so that you can programatically set the value as needed (plus benefit from the other goodies in the FormsModule, which you'll have to import).
You also want to monitor for input events from your search input field, and on each event, update your labels and update your input field as needed.

The above can get you started. Might need extra logic to handle edge cases, might want to add debouncing as needed, but at least this can get you thinking.